# Linq: DataTable to List. Cast issue

Tags: c#, jquery, visual-studio-2010, linq, jqgrid

I'm getting the `Specified cast is not valid.` and I can't find why. Here's my code.

**Object Layer.**

```
public class Supervisor
{
    public long ID { get; set; }
    public string stringField1 { get; set; }
    public string stringField2 { get; set; }
    public string stringField3 { get; set; }
    public int intField1{ get; set; }        
    public int intField2 { get; set; }

}
```

**C# Method.**

```
[WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public static string GetPend(string value1FromjqGrid, string value2FromjqGrid)
    {
        string query = "GetPend";
        string supervisor = "";
        Supervision _query = new Supervision();             
        DataTable dt = _query.GetSupervisorQuery(value1FromjqGrid, value2FromjqGrid, supervisor, query );
        List<Supervisor> lines = (from dt1 in dt.AsEnumerable()
                               select new Supervisor()
                               { 
                                   ID = dt1.Field<long>("ID"),                                                                              
                                   stringField1 = dt1.Field<string>("Linea"),
                                   intField1 = dt1.Field<int>("Tiempo"),
                                   intField2 = dt1.Field<int>("TIPOACTIVIDAD_ID"),
                                   stringField2 = dt1.Field<string>("ACT_ID"),
                                   stringField3 = dt1.Field<string>("OBS")
                               }).ToList();
        var grid = new
        {
            page = 1,
            records = lines.Count(),
            total = lines.Count(),
            rows = from item in lines
                   select new
                   {
                       id = item.ID,
                       cell = new string[]{                               
                           item.stringField1,
                           item.intField1.ToString(),
                           item.intField2.ToString(),
                           item.stringField2,
                           item.stringField3
                       }
                   }
        };
        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(grid); 
    }
```

That's it more or less. When the `LinQ` iteration starts it crashes. The `DataTable` is filled correctly as I've checked, and `dt1` contains the fields correctly. I see the `""` for the string columns and the numbers for the `int's` (I've done the SQL Stored Procedure myself so I did the checking there too.) With this I'm also assuring that the 2 parameters from the `jqGrid` are OK, but still I placed some alerts just right before the calling and yes, they are fine.

I've pasted the code it seems to be relevant since the error comes when the codes trying to parse the information from the `DataTable` to the `List`, if you'd need to check the javascript involved here just let me know but I don't think that's needed.
Clearly I'm not seeing something so hopefully you can guide me in the right direction. Thanks.

PS. I've tried to check it out at LINQPad4 but I can't give it a try since I don't know how to represent the original DataTable variable there.

**Update**.

This is what VS gives to me when I expand the error.:

```
   at System.Data.DataRowExtensions.UnboxT`1.ValueField(Object value)
   at System.Data.DataRowExtensions.Field[T](DataRow row, String columnName)
   at WEB.Supervisor.<GetPend>b__b(DataRow dt1) in       E:\Dev\VS\WEB\Supervisor.aspx.cs:line 110
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at WEB.Supervisor.GetPend(String value1FromjqGrid, String value2FromjqGrid) in E:\Dev\VS\WEB\Supervisor.aspx.cs:line 109
```

Lines 109 and 110 are these

```
List<Supervisor> lines = (from dt1 in dt.AsEnumerable()
                           select new Supervisor()
```

It crashes at the beggining of the convert process.

**UPDATE 2**

According to comments I did as follows.

Took the `SELECT` and turned into a `SELECT INTO` for generating a trash table. Then checked its design and for my honest surprise, the field `CAST(ACT_ID AS NVARCHAR(50))` was still decimal and not nvarchar as I expected.

So, seems like I have to handle this in `LinQ` as a decimal, or could I do something else? I've tried working with `decimals` in the past and didn't succed.

Comment: `Specified cast is not valid` What is the whole message? StackTrace?  Which line?

Comment: sorry, my bad forgetting to append it.

Comment: You cast to `int` and to `long`. Are you sure that the fields are not nullable? You can try to use `int?` and `long?` instead. Then you could replace `item.intField1.ToString()` to something like `null? null: ((int)item.intField1).ToString()`

Comment: @Oleg the cast to `long` that catches your attention comes from a       `SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER ... AS ID` . When I worked with others jqGrid tables giving it a `long` was the only choice I had if I wanted to use `row_number` Do you still think the same way? `int?` didn't seem to work either.

Comment: In any way it should by some type mismatching of `GetSupervisorQuery`. For example `stringField2 = dt1.Field<string>("ACT_ID")` could be integer and you should use `stringField2 = dt1.Field<int>("ACT_ID")` or `intField1 = dt1.Field<int>("Tiempo")` could be string and you should use `intField1 = dt1.Field<string>("Tiempo")`.

Comment: @Oleg `ACT_ID` at `SQL` tables is originaly `decimal`. At `SELECT` time I do a cast to nvarchar so I can use it as string (no need for nothing else). Could it be the problem? Don't know to use decimals in `LinQ`

Comment: So look at the datatable's columns property, go through each column's datatype property to see the actual type and compare it with the type you are using.

Comment: I never used `decimal` type and will probably never do this:-). You can try to comment the line with `stringField2 = dt1.Field<string>("ACT_ID")` to verify that it's the reason.

Comment: apparently it's that. the result of the cast(field as nvarchar(x)) is giving me the original datatype. Updated the question. And no, I don't what decimals in my jqGrid either :(

Comment: @Oleg yes, it iterates if I comment that field. Still, I need it. So guess I should force the cast at SQL time so It doesn't get messy with decimals at jqGrid right?

Comment: Probably `stringField2 = dt1.Field<decimal>("ACT_ID").ToString()` will work?

Comment: @Oleg it's working, or at least I've collected all the values :) Please, feel free to ANSWER the question so I can give you the credit since you've helped a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be type mismatch between column type in the database and the type of data used in `List<Supervisor> lines = (from dt1 in dt.AsEnumerable() select new Supervisor() {...}).ToList();`.

After some conversation in comments we could see that the type of `"ACT_ID"` is decimal in the `database`. So to fix the exception problem one can do something like the following:

```
List<Supervisor> lines = (from dt1 in dt.AsEnumerable()
                          select new Supervisor {
                              ID = dt1.Field<long>("ID"),
                              stringField1 = dt1.Field<string>("Linea"),
                              intField1 = dt1.Field<int>("Tiempo"),
                              intField2 = dt1.Field<int>("TIPOACTIVIDAD_ID"),
                              stringField2 = dt1.Field<decimal>("ACT_ID").ToString(),
                              stringField3 = dt1.Field<string>("OBS")
                          }).ToList();
```